# Getting Date in JSTL using EL Expressions

Tags: java, date, jsp, servlets, jstl

As of I know that

```
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />

<fmt:formatDate var="year" value="${now}" pattern="yyyy" />

<p>Current year: ${year}</p>
```

this will gives current Year but I needed to check  if the current date is < 10th of the current month or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest I could code.

```
<%@ page import="java.time.LocalDate" %>
<%
    pageContext.setAttribute("lDate", LocalDate.now());
%>
Is today before the 10th of the month? ${lDate.dayOfMonth < 10}
```

Comment: Thanks @rickz  it is Working!.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use scriptlets,

```
<c:set var="now" value="java.time.LocalDateTime.now()"/>
```